# Чем отличаются слова "народно-поэтический" и "устно-поэтический"?

Tags: лексика, семантика

Как определить значение слова ***устно-поэтический***, если его нет в  словаре? Это важно знать, чтобы объяснить форму написания сложного прилагательного (недавний вопрос на форуме).

Наверное, надо посмотреть в Интернете.  И действительно, такая тема там нашлась, но, увы, без ответа. Поэтому я ее просто перепишу:

**Устное народное творчество (фольклор)** имеет разные жанры, в том числе **лирический жанр** (например, любовные, семейные, колыбельные и обрядовые песни).

Этот жанр можно назвать **народно-поэтическим творчеством**. Его особенности: устный характер (передача из уст в уста) и анонимность (автор неизвестен).

А в каком случае используется сочетание "устно-поэтическое творчество", эти понятия **взаимозаменяемы?**

Также **устная поэзия и народная поэзия** — это одно и то же? Может быть, эти слова были синонимичны только до определенного времени?

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3325069-chem-otlichajutsja-slova-narodno-poeticheskij-i-ustno-poeticheskij.html

Comment: Вы же сами написали: Этот жанр можно назвать народно-поэтическим творчеством. Его особенности: устный характер (передача из уст в уста). Поэтому я считаю, что это то же самое.

Comment: https://bigenc.ru/ethnology/text/4702850